# Django models, filter based on the division of two fields

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble understanding the annotate of django models.
I am trying to build a datatable where one of its value is the division of two fields that might contain zeros and filter the rest based on the user input so what I tried so far is:

model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    unit_per_item = models.FloatField(default=1)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

views

```
from django.db.models import Q, F, Case, When, FloatField
from .models import Item

if request.POST['search[value]']:
        model_obj = Item.objects.annotate(
            unit_price = Case(
                When(Q(item_price__exact=0) | Q(unit_per_item__exact=0), then=0),
                default=F("item_price") / F("unit_per_item"),
                output_field=FloatField()
            )
        ).filter(
            Q(item_name__icontains=request.POST['search[value]'])|
            Q(item_price__icontains=request.POST['search[value]'])|
            Q(unit_per_item__icontains=request.POST['search[value]'])|
            Q(description__icontains=request.POST['search[value]'])|
            Q(unit_price__icontains=request.POST['search[value]'])
        )[start:length]
```

But I am getting an error that says

`RegisterLookupMixin.get_lookup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lookup_name'`

or

```
'float' object is not callable
```

after removing the `output_field`

What I am essentially trying to achieve here in SQL is this

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    item_price/unit_per_item AS unit_price 
FROM 
    inventory_item 
WHERE 
    item_name LIKE '%some_value%' OR
    item_price LIKE '%some_value%' OR
    unit_per_item LIKE '%some_value%' OR
    description LIKE '%some_value%' OR
    CONVERT(
        CASE WHEN item_price=0 OR unit_per_item=0 THEN
            item_price
        ELSE
            item_price/unit_per_item
        END,
    CHAR) LIKE '%some_value%';
```

I am honestly a little lost at this point, if there is a documentation that can expound further the model filters of django that would also be helpful or maybe I missed something.